# Is the below setTimeout JavaScript code leaking?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I've got a method which loops through the favicon of a website:

```
function LoopFavIcon(isRed){
 if(!tabInFocus)
 {
    isRed = GetBoolean(isRed, false);

    if(isRed)
    {
        $($('head link')[0]).attr("href", "favicon.ico");
    }
    else
    {
        $($('head link')[0]).attr("href", "favicon_red.ico");
    }
    setTimeout(function f83(){
        LoopFavIcon(!isRed)
    }, 700);
 }}
```

The memory timeline seems to add memory, without a GC to occur:

[image: Increasing heap memory]

It's possible that the measured time interval wasn't enough for the GC to kick in, but I have my doubts. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't look like it is leaking (can be wrong though), just manually run a GC to check it out.

Comment: Worth noting, perhaps, that once `tabInFocus` is falsy once, the timer loop will never restart (barring something not shown restarting it).

Comment: @X.L.Ant thanks for all the comments. I didn't realize that you could force GC during a timeline recording. The memory dropped to the base, so it looks like everything is OK

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown what's in `GetBoolean`, but assuming it's not doing something it shouldn't, no, there's no memory leak in that code. You just didn't run it for long enough to do GC. (Chrome's tools also let you force a GC.)

Remember that one of the key aspects of a garbage-collected environment is that the environment will do garbage collection *as and when needed*, and not typically before.

Comment: Sorry about, it was an oversight and thanks for the suggestions